# Location based segmentation of objects in an image (in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I've been working on an image segmentation problem and can't seem to get a good idea for my most recent problem.

This is what I have at the moment:

[Click here for image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtblt.png) (This is only a generic example.)

Is there a robust algorithm that can automatically discard the right square as not belonging to the group of the other four squares (that I know should always be stacked more or less on top of each other) ?

It can sometimes be the case, that one of the stacked boxes is not found, so there's a gap or that the bogus box is on the left side.

Your input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what the deviation from the stacked boxes is? What does "more or less mean"? Do you have multiple images so that you can derive some statistics or similar?

Comment: The deviation I don't know in numbers, but if the previous algorithm works as it should, then the boxes need to at least overlap by about 3/4. I have 5 images of various quality, which also leads to my other problem. Sometimes multiple boxes within the stack are not found (there is always just one "true" stack) which in turn leads to the boxes not overlapping as much as previous mentioned.      And just to clarify, there can theoretically be two or more bogus boxes, though this is unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a way of producing BW images like your example:

```
s  = regionprops(BW, 'centroid');
centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);
```

`xpos = centroids(:,1);` should then be the x-positions of the boxes.

From here you have multiple ways to go, depending on whether you always have just one  separated box and one set of grouped boxes or not.  For the "one bogus box far away, rest closely grouped" case (away from Matlab, so this is unchecked) you could even do something as simple as:

```
d = abs(xpos-median(xpos));
bogusbox = centroids(d==max(d),:);
imshow(BW);
hold on;
plot(bogusbox(1),bogusbox(2),'r*');
```

Making something that's robust for your actual use case which I am assuming doesn't consist of neat boxes is another matter; as suggested in comments, you need some idea of how close together the positioning of your good boxes is, and how separate the bogus box(es) will be.

For example, you could use other `regionprops` measurements such as `'BoundingBox'` or `'Extrema'` and define some sort of measurement of how much the boxes overlap in x relative to each other, then group using that (this could be made to work even if you have multiple stacks in an image).

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out as soon as possible. I already had the centroids of the boxes calculated by the bounding box sounds like a good possibility. I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked. This seems to work fine for one bogus box. I will adapt it slightly to account for multiple boxes, but that should be easy.